# Hover child DIV and change style of other parent DIV

Tags: html, hover, parent

I'm trying to make a quite simple CSS hover effect.

```
<div class="menu">
     <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="nav">
     <div class="item1"></div>
</div>
```

What I woud like to happen, is that when you hover `<div class="child"></div>` it changes the element style of `<div class="nav"></div>` I've tried a lot of things like

```
.child:hover ~ .nav { }
```

But of course when I do this, it will search for a DIV with the class 'nav' inside the parent DIV '.menu', right?

I also tried

```
.child:hover .nav {
```

}

and

```
.child:hover + .nav {
}
```

I do feel a little bit stupid for asking this question, because the solution is probably pretty easy, but I have been trying to solve this problem for a few hours now...

Comment: i think unless you wrap the menu div and nav div into one wrapper div, you'll have to use jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using jQuery, you can use `.hover()` to add css to the nav div like below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.child').hover(function() {
    $('.nav').toggleClass('myStyle');
  });
});
```

```css
.myStyle {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
     Menu Element
     <div class="child">Child Element</div>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  Nav Element
     <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot! Such a shame it isn't possible with just pure CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot control a parent element using pure CSS.

jQuery is your best bet here, like:

```
$('.child').hover(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('someClassForParentStyling');
}, function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('someClassForParentStyling');
});
```

In your CSS, have the styling you want for the parent element set like:

```
.someClassForParentStyling {
  background: #efefef;
}
```